# Resize image file size by inputted percentage value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to write script to resize the image file size by the given percentage value. My script is as below:

```js
let canvas;
let array_WH = new Array();
let percent = 50;
let img = new Image();

$(function() {

  function ff(height, width, percentage) {

    var newHeight = height * (percentage / 100);

    var newWidth = width * (percentage / 100);

    return [newWidth, newHeight];
  }

  $("#file_select").change(function(e) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(e) {



      img.onload = function() {

        array_WH = ff(img.width, img.height, percent);

        console.log('old width: ' + img.width);
        console.log('new width: ' + array_WH[0]);

        width = array_WH[0];

        height = array_WH[1];

        if (canvas) return;

        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        canvas.width = width;

        canvas.height = height;

        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);

        // //Line added
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
        // //Line edited
        this.src = canvasData;
        // //Line added
        console.log(canvasData.length * 3 / 4, ' bytes');

        document.body.appendChild(this); //remove this if you don't want to show it

      }

      img.src = e.target.result;

    }

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<h1 class="logo">Upload Picture</h1>
<div id="upload_form_div">
  <form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" capture="camera" id="file_select" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
  Uploading your picture...
</div>
```

You can [FiddleJs](http://jsfiddle.net/34fzc9mj/) for demo here.

Let's say percentage is 50%, therefore `function ff(height, width, percentage) {...}` supposed to return new width the half of old width, and new height the half of old height, and consequently, the half size of old image size as a result.

However, it does not works the way it is expected. I tested by uploading image file of 3.00 MB (width: 58000px, height: 3867px), then the function produced new image file of 9.5 MB (width: 1933px, height: 2900px), which is far from correct file size that is 1.5 MB the half of old image size.

How could I correct my function to achieve the expected result by the given percentage? Thanks.

Comment: The file size of an image is not solely dependent on how many pixels it contains. And even if it were, cutting two dimensions in half yields an image with 1/4 the pixels.

Comment: @AuxTaco thanks, what’s it depend on, how can we do to reduce their size? I’ve read from other source and some lib the does not do anything beside cutting of the image pixel of width and height.

Answer (score 0):

1) Changed order in ff call

```
array_WH = ff(img.height, img.width, percent);
```

2) Added parameters: type 'image/jpeg' and quality of jpeg 0.5

```
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5)
```

Here is edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2pu4tmkr/

Comment: thanks very much, I have add fiddle in question already, you can test with any upload image, I wish the size of image would reduce 50% of the original size. Thanks. :)